# How to Create String Array List that removes Strings that are already contained in list

Tags: java

I am trying to add "Luis" 3 times to array list and then remove "Luis" so there is only one "Luis". Seems to be a problem with the if.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Menu {
    private ArrayList<String> meals;

    public Menu() {
        this.meals = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    // Implement the methods here
    public void addMeals() {

        this.meals.add("Luis");
        this.meals.add("Luis");
        this.meals.add("Luis");
        for (String container : this.meals) {
            for (int counter = 0; counter < this.meals.size(); counter++) {
                ***if (counter > 1 && this.meals.contains(container)) {
                    this.meals.remove(this.meals.indexOf(container));
                }***
            }
        }
        System.out.println(this.meals);
    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like a homework.

Comment: Not homework, just preparing for a class that I will take soon :P

Comment: You are adding to ArrayList,not to array?

Comment: Won't this throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`? You are removing an element from the list while iterating over it.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes. That is what I am getting. How could I solve this?

Comment: Well, for starters, you could update your question to specify that is the part that is not working.

Comment: Here is how you would do it without an error. https://repl.it/BTPA/1

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I understand why we need 
import java.util.ArrayList;
but do we really need import java.util.Iterator;  ?

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayList` can contain duplicates. There are other Java collection classes which can only contain unique elements, such as `Set`.

I'd suggest you look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) for Set and its implementations, this would likely solve your issue.

Comment: You are forgetting this is probably assignment, and in assignments the code has to follow crazy rules, just because. Even if there is better way to eliminate the pre-condition altogether before it occurs due to poor design, it has to happen, so you can try to "eliminate" it..